# What's the difference between monosgen-2.0.dll and libmonosgen-2.0.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mono, mono-embedding

I'm trying to embed Mono in a `c` program as in http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/ with SGen GC.
In the mono distribution in `C:\Program Files\Mono\bin` there are two different mono dll with SGen support:

- monosgen-2.0.dll, size : 3,082 KB
- libmonosgen-2.0.dll, size : 14,801 KB

The tutorial says `On Windows, depending on the GC implementation to be used (... SGen), you need to link your application with ... monosgen-2.0.lib`, but it says nothing about what dll I have to use. I'm confused because [this tutorial](http://www.giorgosdimtsas.net/embedding-mono-in-your-c-application/) says I should rename `libmonosgen-2.0.dll` to `monosgen-2.0.dll` (but why?). Sample program compiles and works fine with both of these libs. Dependency walker shows that `libmonosgen-2.0.dll` exports more symbols than the `monosgen-2.0.dll`. So what the actual difference between these libs?